# How to change the formatting (style) on the hierarchy of sections in latex document

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, sectioning, article

I am trying to follow the formatting guide of my course. After trying to find some information on this, I have reached no solution. I would appreciate any and all help towards this.

I am using the `article` class.

> *The image below shows the formatting I need to follow.*

[image: desired output]

Comment: If not only hiding/showing but also the formatting of the entries is part of the question, have a look at [packages like `etoc`, `tocbasic`, `tocloft` etc.](https://ctan.org/topic/toc-etc). There are already several questions/answers about using these on TEX.SX. And please *always* show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and use it to explain the wanted changes.

Comment: Hiding section levels on `toc` is only part of the question. Formatting the hierarchy of sections is the most important. I was looking for that on google, but did not find any answers, I was probably using the wrong keywords as I know pretty much nothing about this topic or `Latex` in general. I thought tha the image provided was enough to convey the idea and show how the document should look when applying the desired formatting. 

@cabohah thanks for the recommendations, as they provide me with an starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `report` (or `book`) class that provides a `\chapter`, since that's what is displayed in your image.

The following minimal example provides the levels you need in the following commands:

1. `\chapter`
2. `\section`
3. `\subsection`
4. `\subsubsection`
5. `\paragraph`

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}% Show sectional unit numbering up to level 3 (\subsubsection)

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                        {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                        {-1em}%
                                        {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\textbullet\quad}}
\let\old@seccntformat\@seccntformat
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{subsubsection}=0 .\fi% Add period after \subsubsection number
  \quad
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection}}% Update formatting of \subsubsection heading numbering

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}% Just for this example
\chapter{First level}

\lipsum[1][1]

\setcounter{section}{2}% Just for this example
\section{Second level}

\lipsum[1][2]

\setcounter{subsection}{5}% Just for this example
\subsection{Third level}

\lipsum[1][3]

\subsubsection{Fourth level}

\lipsum[1][4]

\paragraph{Fifth level}

\lipsum[1][5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @werner, this is really close to what I was trying to accomplish. It is a huge help.